# Game Engine: Disable/Enable Keyboard/Mouse input

Tags: python, game-engine

Is it possible to disable and enable the mouse/keyboard input in blender that every sensor doesn't recognize any input while it's disabled? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no settings that disables all sensors, or all sensors of a certain kind (at least I do not know). You can disable sensors individually when you use blender (not when your game session is running):

[image]